# Issue in Ionic production build for Mapbox GL JS feature

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, mapbox, ionic3, mapbox-gl-js

I am developing an simple application using ionic 3. Integrating Mapbox GL JS to my application.
In home page, i am viewing the particular location using mapbox.

Using ionic cordova build android or ionic cordova build android --release, i am able to view the map from the output of the build
But for production build i.e ionic cordova build android --prod --release, i am not able to view the map

The same thing happened for browser build.
I am using mapbox GL JS version as mapbox-gl@^0.37.0.

Code snippets taken from the below url
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/examples/1 
for display a map.
Is anyone tried out the same?

Code is in Github
https://github.com/livingmana/myApp

I would appreciate any help on the same.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: I think i'm having a similar issue, something that happens during the --prod flag is breaking something for the mapbox initialization code, I found a guy that was having this issue and solved it by loading the code from the mapbox cdn instead of from the package and he got around the issue in that way, seems a hacky method to me though. I think the best would be to gather as much information as possible and then raise an Issue on the plugin github page, see if someone can find the offending code.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, the --prod build definitely breaks the mapbox gl maps.